# Cannot get any file count of sub-directories and files in MyDocuments C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use the following code to try and count up all the directories and files inside MyDocuments.

This code works with all other special folders (Favorites, Desktop, Photos, etc.)

But when I try to get the count of 'My Documents', it fails.

```
            /*DOCUMENTS*/               
            documentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(documentsFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length; //THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS - DOES NOT GET PAST HERE
            MessageBox.Show(fileCount.ToString()); //THIS NEVER SHOWS
```

It fails when I try to get the fileCount - which works when I get the counts in other directories.

That directory is fairly large in size on my PC - so maybe I need to 'wait' while it counts?

I can't figure out why it's not working but all the others work just fine without issue using basically the same code.

Comment: Can you give me errors ?

Comment: It's odd because it doesn't kick off errors - it just ends the process and moves onto the next bits of code.

Comment: I think you have access denied in some subfolder of this... I tried your piece of code and this is what is failing. Code return a exception. Put a try catch on it.

Comment: Yes. I also faced the same error.Error regarding access denied.

Comment: Alright - I will do the try/catch. Is there a bit of code to ignore 'access denied' folders?

Comment: You guys were right - access denied! I think it is probably access to the My Music / My Pictures, etc. libraries that is causing the issue. 

That can be worked around I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I can think of is excluding the folders with no access from the file count

```
int fileCount = 0;
var pathToSearch = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

//retrieve files
fileCount += Directory.GetFiles(pathToSearch, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;

//retrieve folders
foreach (var subFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(pathToSearch, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
    try { Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(subFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories), f => fileCount++); }
    catch { }        
}

MessageBox.Show($"{fileCount}");
```